# Gnome Shell got removed after updating Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, gnome, updates

Now when i try to install it...it shows the following error

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-shell : Depends: libgcr-3-1 (>= 3.4.0) but 3.2.2-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
               Depends: gir1.2-gcr-3 but it is not installable
               Recommends: gnome-contacts but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can I install GNOME-Shell?

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

I had the same problem before. This problem occurred after I allowed the "partial upgrade" in the update manager, which caused the gnome-shell being removed. I try the above commands, and then the gnome-shell is able to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the commands below.

```
sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo apt-get clean

sudo apt-get update
```

Once you do that, then you can run: `sudo apt-get install gnome-shell`